# Google App Engine Backend - Java Data Model - Bitmap

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, bitmap

I´m coding an app that will allow the user to take a picture, add some title and description to it and upload it to a server. That package (picture+title+description) is named "Gift".

I've used Google´s automated Backend Engine generator and added an @Entity class named Gift which contains all the variables and a constructor to build a "Gift" inside a new project that was created named AppEngine. (I followed this Google tutorial: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities).

My question is basically, how can I interact with that "Gift" class that before was on my main package inside my application and now is on the AppEngine src folder?

For example, before, whenever I wanted to create a new "Gift" and upload it, I simply instantiated a new "Gift" using it´s constructor. Now, it´s not possible to do that, as Eclipse is forcing me to use a "Gift" class inside a package that was auto-generated (com.package.app.giftendpoit.model).

That new Gift class (called Java Data Model) starts with these lines:

```
/**
 * Model definition for Gift.
 * This is the Java data model class that specifies how to parse/serialize
 * into the JSON that is transmitted over HTTP when working with the giftendpoint. 
 * @author Google, Inc.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public final class Gift extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {

@com.google.api.client.util.Key
private Bitmap bmp;

(...)
```

When I try to create a new Gift on my application and set it´s Bitmap, I get the following error message on Eclipse:

*The method setBmp(com.package.app.giftendpoint.model.Bitmap) in the type Gift is not applicable for the arguments (android.graphics.Bitmap)*

Here´s part of the original Gift class that still exists on the auto-generated AppEngine project, but not on my application:

```
@Entity
public class Gift {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String title;
private String description;
private Bitmap bmp;

public Gift(String title, String description, Bitmap bmp) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.bmp = bmp;
}

//Getters & Setters (ie. SetBmp (Bitmap bitmap)...)
```

The Title and the Description of the Gift are set without errors, but not the Bitmap. Here´s the code I´m using to do that:

```
public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

           Giftendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new  Giftendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
           Giftendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();
  try {
      gift = new Gift();
      gift.setTitle(title);
      gift.setDescription(description);
      gift.setBmp(bmp); // Error:The method setBmp(com.package.app.giftendpoint.model.Bitmap) in the type Gift is not applicable for the arguments (android.graphics.Bitmap)

      Gift result = endpoint.insertGift(gift).execute();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
      return (long) 0;
    }
}
```

Any tips on how I may solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I just altered all the Model´s variables and methods that referred to a Bitmap to android.graphics.Bitmap instead of just Bitmap (which was being referred to com.packege.app.giftendpoint.model.Bitmap). I´ll do some tests here to see if this change is any good.

Comment: The above said does not work as every time the project is rebuilt, android.graphics.Bitmap is altered back to Bitmap on the Gift Model.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just figured it out that I should use a Blob instead of a Bitmap. Here´s the code converting an image to a blob:

```
    byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    bmpBlob = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I also updated my Entity to use Blob instead of bitmap.